# Non-trivial algorithm conversion from imperative to functional

Tags: list, algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

To enforce my (weak) functional programming skills, I am studying *The NURBS book* by *Piegl* and *Tiller* converting all the algorithms to Haskell. It is a very nice and instructive process but I got stuck on algorithm 2.2, here is (a C-like reworked-by-me version of) the pseudo-code:

```c
double[] BasisFuns( int i, double u, int p, double U[]) {
  double N[p+1];
  double left[p+1];
  double ritght[p+1];
  N[0]=1.0;
  for (j=1; j<=p; j++) {
    left[j]  = u - U[i+1-j];
    right[j] = U[i+j] - u;
    double saved = 0.0;
    for (r=O; r<j; r++) {
      double temp= N[r]/(right[r+1]+left[j-r]);
      N[r] = saved+right[r+1]*temp;
      saved = left[j-r]*temp;
    }
    N[j] = saved;
  }
  return N;
}
```

The outer loop looks easy, but the inner one, with all those necessarily-ordered modifications to the elements of `N` is giving me a headache.

I started to set it up like this:

```
baseFunc :: RealFrac a => Int -> Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
baseFunc i p u knots
  [ ??? | j <- [1..p], r <- [0..j] ]
  where
  left = [ u - knots !! (i+1-j) | j <- [ 1 .. p ]
  right= [ knots !! (i+j) - u   | j <- [ 1 .. p ]
```

but I feel that I may be completely off road.

I have already written a completely different and inefficient version of this function based on Eq. 2.5 in the book, therefore here I am looking to maintain the performance of the imperative version.

Comment: I am not sure this can be translated well. It exploits a lot of random access to arrays, and there's mutation everywhere. Especially where performance is an issue I'd convert this to Haskell keeping its imperative nature and using, say, `STUArray` and the `ST` monad.

Comment: Translating directly from C is probably *not* the way to maintain the performance. The compiler does more than you give it credit for.

Comment: @chepner The book provides the recursive equations as well (Eq. 2.5). I am not sure that they are appropriate for this venue. Anyway starting from them, it is really *easy* to get a working implementation in Haskell, but getting something that is as efficient as the pseudocode above seems... *hard*

Comment: Granted, you can't really benchmark until you have both working implementations, but I suspect you underestimating what the compiler can *do* with the recursive definitions. I suspect even an optimizing C compiler would generate something quite different from what you would expect given that C code.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Although it is certainly possible to translate numerical algorithms into Haskell starting from Fortran/Matlab/C “everything is an array” style (and, using unboxed mutable vectors, performance will generally be not much worse) this is really missing the point about using a functional language. The *underlying math* is actually much closer to functional than to imperative programming, so the best thing is to start right there. Specifically, the recurrence formula

[image: equation 2.5 from the NURBS book]

can be translated almost literally into Haskell, much better than into an imperative language:

```
baseFuncs :: [Double]  -- ^ Knots, \(\{u_i\}_i\)
          -> Int       -- ^ Index \(i\) at which to evaluate
          -> Int       -- ^ Spline degree \(p\)
          -> Double    -- ^ Position \(u\) at which to evaluate
          -> Double
baseFuncs us i 0 u
  | u >= us!!i, u < us!!(i+1)  = 1
  | otherwise                  = 0
baseFuncs us i p u
      = (u - us!!i)/(us!!(i+p) - us!!i) * baseFuncs us i (p-1) u
       + (us!!(i+p+1) - u)/(us!!(i+p+1) - us!!(i+1)) * baseFuncs us (i+1) (p-1) u
```

Unfortunately this will actually not be efficient though, for multiple reasons.

First, lists suck at random-access. A simple fix is to switch to unboxed (but pure) vectors. While we're at is let's wrap them in a newtype because the *u*<sub>*i*</sub> are supposed to be strictly increasing. Talking about types: the direct accesses are unsafe; we could fix this by bringing `p` and the number of segments to the type level and only allowing indices `i < n-p`, but I won't go into that here.

Also, it's awkward to pass `us` and `u` around all the way down the recursion, better just bind it once and then use a helper function to go down:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed (Vector, (!))
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU

newtype Knots = Knots {getIncreasingKnotsSeq :: Vector Double}

baseFuncs :: Knots     -- ^ \(\{u_i\}_i\)
          -> Int       -- ^ Index \(i\) at which to evaluate
          -> Int       -- ^ Spline degree \(p\)
          -> Double    -- ^ Position \(u\) at which to evaluate
          -> Double
baseFuncs (Knots us) i₀ p₀ u = go i₀ p₀
 where go i 0
        | u >= us!i
        , i>=VU.length us-1 || u < us!(i+1)  = 1
        | otherwise                          = 0
       go i p
           = (u - us!i)/(us!(i+p) - us!i) * go i (p-1)
            + (us!(i+p+1) - u)/(us!(i+p+1) - us!(i+1)) * go (i+1) (p-1)
```

The other thing that's not optimal is that we don't share the lower-level evaluations between neighbouring recursive calls. (The evaluation is effectively spanning a directed graph with <sup>*p*<sup>2</sup></sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> nodes, but we evaluate it as a tree with 2<sup>*p*</sup> nodes.) That's a *massive* inefficiency for large *p*, but actually quite harmless for the typical low-degree splines.

The way to avoid this inefficiency is to *memoise*. The C version does this explicitly with the `N` array, but – this being Haskell – we can be lazy to save the effort of allocating the correct size by using a generic memoisation library, e.g. [memo-trie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.10/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html):

```
import Data.MemoTrie (memo2)

baseFuncs (Knots us) i₀ p₀ u = go' i₀ p₀
 where go i 0
        | u >= us!i
        , i>=VU.length us || u < us!(i+1)  = 1
        | otherwise                        = 0
       go i p
           = (u - us!i)/(us!(i+p) - us!i) * go' i (p-1)
            + (us!(i+p+1) - u)/(us!(i+p+1) - us!(i+1)) * go' (i+1) (p-1)
       go' = memo2 go
```

That was the no-brains version (“just memoise the entire domain of `go`”). As dfeuer remarks, it is easy enough to explicitly memoise only the regian that actually gets evaluated, and then we can again use an efficient unboxed vector:

```
baseFuncs (Knots us) i₀ p₀ u = VU.unsafeHead $ gol i₀ p₀
 where gol i 0 = VU.generate (p₀+1) $ \j ->
        if u >= us!(i+j)
            && (i+j>=VU.length us || u < us!(i+j+1))
         then 1 else 0
       gol i p = case gol i (p-1) of
        res' -> VU.izipWith
         (\j l r -> let i' = i+j
            in (u - us!i')/(us!(i'+p) - us!i') * l
            + (us!(i'+p+1) - u)/(us!(i'+p+1) - us!(i'+1)) * r)
         res' (VU.unsafeTail res')
```

(I can safely use `unsafeHead` and `unsafeTail` here, because at each recursion level the zipping reduces the length by 1, so at the top-level I still have `p₀ - (p₀-1) = 1` elements left.)

This version should, I think, have the same asymptotics as the C version. With some more small improvements like precomputing the interval lengths and pre-checking that the arguments are in the allowed range so all accesses can be made `unsafe`, it is probably very close in performance to the C version.

As – again – dfeuer remarks, it might not even be necessary to use vectors there because I just zip together the result. For this kind of stuff, GHC can be very good at optimising code even when using plain lists. But, I won't investigate the performance any further here.

---

The test I used to confirm it actually works:

[image: plot of the base splines]

https://gist.github.com/leftaroundabout/4fd6ef8642029607e1b222783b9d1c1e

Comment: Thanks a lot for your deep insight. Your fist version is very similar to the one that I wrote. But this function gets called an insane amount of times in the following computations and I hate wasting time and electricity! If Haskell cannot easily match the performances of the imperative version on such a purely computational task, maybe there is little benefit for me to set apart my 10+ years of experience with C++

Comment: It _can_ easily match the performance of the imperative version, by _writing_ imperative code (in the `ST` monad). Or just write it in C and link to Haskell using FFI, which is always an option. My point was that this is not _typically_ a sensible approach, because you lose the benefits of having a functional language. But sure, when you've determined that this function is the bottleneck you can always still change it to ugly imperative style.

Comment: Any log(n) performance loss would be coming from MemoTrie. Why not just use a boxed vector and let laziness do its job?

Comment: @Carl yeah, that could be a first step of trading in some elegance for performance. But if you do it too lazily then it will actually be _slower_ than the memo-trie version, namely, if you allocate a large vector of never-used thunks the memory overhead can outweight the access savings. So, if going to vectors at all, I would right away compute the actually-used sizes and make them unboxed to also reap the cache advantages.

Comment: At first glance, it seems to me that there's more structure to the recursion that you can take advantage of. `go i p` calls `go i (p-1)` and `go (i+1) (p-1)`. In particular, the second argument always changes by the same amount.

Comment: I think you can probably write `glo` to replace `go`, where `go i p = glo p !! (i - i0)`.

Comment: @dfeuer right, but then you're just replacing _O_ (log _n_) trie lookups with _O_ (_p_) list lookups, no? –But, this is probably the way to go when passing through unboxed vectors.

Comment: @DarioP I updated according to David's comment. If you check how much the performance lags behin C anymore, I'd be interested in hearing it...

Comment: No, I don't *think* so. The lists get zipped like those vectors, and you take the head of the first one. For the vector approach, can't you make it go forwards (tail recursive)?

Comment: Å right, just see it now after having written the vector version that it could actually just as well be lists. — Do you think tail recursion could give any improvement here? I rather doubt it, because a new vector is allocated regardless. In fact, if I were to guess now I'd say that a list non-tail version might be fastest (save for a mutable-vector imitation of the C example) because GHC can optimise that best.

Comment: I would bet a tail-recursive unboxed vector version would be the fastest "pure" way, but I haven't really thought through the operational "shape" of the list computation.

Comment: I still have to get to the point of being able to effectively benchmark Haskell code. However if you would like, here is the C version https://gist.github.com/dpellegr/3a1f266d34bd7f4462e6bf7004380074. The computation is carried out for a particular degree *p*. For a benchmark closer to a real-life scenario it is probably helpful to increase the size of the knot vector to at least few hundreds.

Answer (score 3):

(Disclaimer: I have zero idea of what is being calculated here.)

The access pattern in the array `U` seems to be as follows: from the index `i` outwards, we consume values to the left and to the right. We could imagine having two lists which consisted precisely in those sequences of elements. In fact, we could construct such lists out of a source list like this:

```
pryAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
pryAt i xs = go i ([], xs)
  where
    go 0 a = a
    go n (us, v : vs) = go (pred n) (v : us, vs)
-- pryAt 5 ['a'..'x']
-- ("edcba","fghijklmnopqrstuvwx")
```

For random-access containers, we could have specialized versions of `pryAt`, because traversing the whole list until we reach the `i`th element will be inefficient.

In the outer loop, we have arrays `N`, `left` and `right` which grow with each iteration (`N` seems to be fully reconstructed at each iteration, as well). We could represent them as lists. In each iteration, we also consume a pair of elements of `U`, to the left and right.

The following datatype represents the situation at the beginning of an iteration of the outer loop:

```
data State = State
  { ns :: [Double],
    left :: [Double],
    right :: [Double],
    us :: ([Double], [Double])
  }
```

Assuming we already had the `outerStep :: State -> State` implemented, we could simply turn the crank `p` times:

```
basis :: Int -> Double -> Int -> [Double] -> [Double]
basis i u p us =
  ns $ iterate outerStep initial !! p
  where
    initial =
      State
        { ns = [1.0],
          left = [],
          right = [],
          us = pryAt i us
        }
```

What is done at `outerStep`? We add new elements to `left` and `right`, then we re-create the whole `N` list from the beginning, while carrying a `saved` accumulator along the way. This is a [`mapAccumR`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-OldList.html#v:mapAccumR). We need some extra info: the `right` values (in the same direction as `N`) and the `left` values (in reverse direction) so we need to zip them beforehand:

```
    outerStep (State {ns, left, right, us = (ul : uls, ur : urs)}) =
      let left' = u - ul : left
          right' = ur - u : right
          (saved', ns') = mapAccumR innerStep 0.0 $ zip3 ns right' (reverse left')
       in State
            { ns = saved' : ns',
              left = left',
              right = right',
              us = (uls, urs)
            }
```

And here are the computations of the inner step:

```
    innerStep saved (n, r, l) = 
        let temp = n / (r - l)
            n' = saved + r
            saved' = l * temp
         in (saved', n')
```

In addition to correcting possible bugs, more work would remain because the `basis` function in its current form is likely to leak memory (in particular, that `mapAccumR` will create lots of thunks). Perhaps it could be rewritten to use functions like [`iterate'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:iterate-39-) or `foldl'` that keep their accumulators strict.

Comment: Along with `mapAccumR`, `reverse` is problematic for lists.

Comment: Perhaps `mapAccumL` could be used instead of `mapAccumR`. `mapAccumL` isn't strict on the accumulator out of the box, but it seems we can ensure that by making the function argument strict on the accumulator: `let (_,xs) = mapAccumL (\ !acc b -> (acc + b,b)) undefined (take 10000000 [0::Int ..]) in take 10 xs`. https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2012-November/018775.html  Also, perhaps `Data.Sequence.Seq`s could be used instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it will work, but...:

```hs
baseFunc :: RealFrac a => Int -> Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
baseFunc i p u knots =
    foldl' helper [1.0] [1..p]

    where
    left = [ u - knots !! (i+1-j) | j <- [ 1 .. p ] ]
    right= [ knots !! (i+j) - u   | j <- [ 1 .. p ] ]

    helper  N  j = outer_loop j N left right

    inner_loop :: RealFrac a => Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> a -> (a, a)
    inner_loop  r  j  N  left  right  saved =
        let temp = N !! r / (right !! (r+1) + left !! (j-r))
        in  (saved + right !! (r+1) * temp, left !! (j-r) * temp)

    outer_loop :: RealFrac a => Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
    outer_loop  j  N  left  right =
        let (new_N, saved) = foldl' helper (N, 0.0) [0..j-1]
            helper  (prev_N, saved)  r = 
                let (N_r, new_saved) = inner_loop r j prev_N left right saved
                in  (insertAt r N_r prev_N, new_saved)
        in  new_N ++ [saved]
```